# SAXException starting Tomhawk2-1.1.10

Tags: jsf, tomcat, myfaces, tomahawk

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem. Have downloaded and configured Myfaces 2.04 and tomahawk2-1.1.10. THe app starts up fine, but the moment it initializes tomahawk, we get the following(The web.xml config is fine as per the myfaces docs):

```
java.io.IOException: Error parsing [jar:file:/C:/FNBConnectProjects/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/webapps/FNBConnectPortal/WEB-INF/lib/tomahawk20-1.1.10.jar!/META-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml]:
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at za.co.fnbconnect.portal.util.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at za.co.fnbconnect.portal.util.StatsFilter.doFilter(StatsFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:/C:/FNBConnectProjects/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/webapps/FNBConnectPortal/WEB-INF/lib/tomahawk20-1.1.10.jar!/META-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml@23,29]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407)
    ... 43 more
```

31 Mar 2011 12:40:54 PM

Comment: Are there no more causes in the trace? The `SAXException` should in turn have another root cause.

Comment: Weirdly no. That is it. I reverted back to what I can only assume is the non-jsf2 version of Tomahawk (tomahawk-1.1.10), and thats starts up fine. However then it looks for something called "oamSubmitForm" in its final rendered javascript. We finally got round THAT problem using a script we created long ago to allow users to press enter on some fields to submit actions. Not ideal, but since we are going live in about 10 hrs...

Comment: I checked the source and made a guess. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:/C:/FNBConnectProjects/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/webapps/FNBConnectPortal/WEB-INF/lib/tomahawk20-1.1.10.jar!/META-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml@23,29]

The error has manifested at line 23, character 29 of `/META-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml` in the JAR. I have the JAR here already and checked the source:

```
20     <facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
21                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
22                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
23                   version="2.0">
24                 
25         <namespace>http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk</namespace>
26         <composite-library-name>org.apache.myfaces.custom</composite-library-name>
```

It's the line with `version="2.0"`. This suggests a version conflict. Is the `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file of your webapp declared as per JSF 2.0 and not as 1.2 or something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Config here -->
</faces-config>
```

Comment: I only have these in my faces-config files: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">
<faces-config>

Comment: You definitely need to replace it by a JSF 2.0 one as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a a bug on tomahawk, which was fixed long time ago. See [TOMAHAWK-1560](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1560). If you need a snapshot of tomahawk you can search on [MyFaces Snapshots Repo](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/myfaces)